# SQL Azure : Improve Index Performance

Tags: indexing, azure-sql-database

I have following query :

```
SELECT A.TenantID, A.Latitude AS OriginLat, A.Longitude AS OriginLang, B.Latitude AS DestLat, B.Longitude AS DestLang 
FROM CT as A
INNER JOIN CT AS B ON A.Latitude <> B.Latitude AND A.Longitude<>B.Longitude
Left Outer Join GoogleMatrix g ON ROUND(g.[OriginSiteLat] ,3) = A.Latitude
AND ROUND(g.[OriginSiteLng] ,3) =A.Longitude
AND  ROUND(g.[DestSiteLat],3)  = B.Latitude AND ROUND(g.[DestSiteLng] ,3) = B.Longitude
WHERE g.ID is Null
```

In above, 1000 records left join with 330K records, its taking 5 mins.
I have 2 separate non clustered indexes on OriginSiteLat & OriginSiteLng AND DestSiteLat & DestSiteLng. Following is execution plan :

[image]

Ours is Basic subscription with 5 DTU. Running the query did raise the DTU reading up to 80%. Am not sure if we need to improve indexing or get higher DTUs.

Comment: Can you provide execution plan as xml and copy below query output  in seperate session for every 130 seconds or so,so this will capture all the wait stats..select * from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id=yoursessinid

Comment: @TheGameiswar
Execution Plan : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=17946507658843538875


Execution Log: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=63696418204554989157